# Rounding doubles for use in NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, double, rounding

I have a situation where I have lots of different `double` values, for example `1.00, 0.25 and 2.50`. I would like to round these `doubles` so that they become `1, 0.25 and 2.5`; in other words I want to remove any trailing 0's. Is there a way to do this?

At the moment I have been using `%.2f`, and I'm wondering if I can make use of this but adapt it in some way. Please can someone help me out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as you're talking only about display, this is quite easy. The [format specifier](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) you want is `%g`:

> The double argument shall be converted in the style `f` or `e` (or in the style `F` or `E` in the case of a `G` conversion specifier), with the precision specifying the number of significant digits [...] **Trailing zeros shall be removed from the fractional portion of the result**[...]

```
double twopointfive = 2.500;
double onepointzero = 1.0;
double pointtwofive = .25000000000;
NSLog(@"%g %f", twopointfive, twopointfive);
NSLog(@"%g %f", onepointzero, onepointzero);
NSLog(@"%g %f", pointtwofive, pointtwofive);
```

> 2011-12-06 21:27:59.180 TrailingZeroes[39506:903] 2.5 2.500000
>   2011-12-06 21:27:59.184 TrailingZeroes[39506:903] 1 1.000000
>   2011-12-06 21:27:59.185 TrailingZeroes[39506:903] 0.25 0.250000

The same format specifier can be used with an `NSNumberFormatter`, which will also give you some control over significant digits.

The trailing zeroes can't be removed from the way the number is stored in memory, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want the `%g` format specifier to redact trailing zeros.

Answer (score 1):

*Not really rounding, but have you tried just `%f` it should only show the number of digits required rather then padding out the number.*

My answer above is wrong, `%g` as others has stated is the right way to go.

The documentation for string formatters should help too. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of all the format specifiers that you can use...

```
%@     Object
%d, %i signed int
%u     unsigned int
%f     float/double

%x, %X hexadecimal int
%o     octal int
%zu    size_t
%p     pointer
%e     float/double (in scientific notation)
%g     float/double (as %f or %e, depending on value)
%s     C string (bytes)
%S     C string (unichar)
%.*s   Pascal string (requires two arguments, pass pstr[0] as the first, pstr+1 as the second)
%c     character
%C     unichar

%lld   long long
%llu   unsigned long long
%Lf    long double
```